# How can I add the foreign key transactions (account_id) referencing accounts (account_id) - NOT A PK - in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Accounts table

```
id(PK)
account_id uuid
```

Transactions table

```
id(PK)
transaction_id uuid
account_id uuid (referencing accounts table column account_id)
```

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :transactions, foreign_key: 'account_id'
end
```

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :account, optional: true, foreign_key: 'account_id'
end
```

```
class AddForeignKeyToTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    add_foreign_key "transactions", "accounts", column: :account_id
  end
end
```

This automatically creates an FK Constraint referencing accounts(id) but I'd like to reference accounts(account_id)

Comment: ```add_foreign_key "transactions", "accounts", column: :account_id, primary_key: account_id```